# Cocos2d manual rotation of UIKit when orientation changes

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, rotation

What changes do I need to make to this code in order to get this to work in Cocos2d?   Works great in touch for manually rotating when orientation changes.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:YES andDuration:duration];
    }
    else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self changeTheViewToPortrait:NO andDuration:duration];
    }
}

- (void) changeTheViewToPortrait:(BOOL)portrait andDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    if(portrait){
        //change the view and subview frames for the portrait view
        tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 40);
    }
    else {
        //change the view and subview  frames for the landscape view
        tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 260, 480, 40);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try this in cocos2d? Which cocos2d version? Why not rely on autorotation?

Comment: The tab bar does not rotate in cocos2d.  All cocos2d objects rotate though.  For some reason, even with GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController they don't rotate.  That might be the real issue.

Comment: can you use cocos2d 2.0? v1.x doesn't have all the fixes for iOS 6 autorotation

Comment: @user2093708: Have you managed to solve your issue?